# What happened to the car?

Tags: starting

today I tried innova crysta.. so when I started the car *forgot to putdown the handbrake* I started to put on my reverse gear while pressing the brake and the handbrake on so when I put it in reverse it, suddenly the car automatically moved a little bit back and stoped on putting to reverse and an battery sign appeard on the multi information display... What happened there? Did I damaged my car?

Comment: Are you having any trouble with the car at this time?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just stalled the engine.

The battery light would come on to indicate that it was not receiving charge because the engine had stopped.

Did you have to restart the engine?

You won’t have damaged anything.